# permanently deleted user does not show up in groups delta query response in members@delta with @removed property

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I was going through this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#deltalink-response to get incremental changes for groups. I have an AAD group in which I added 5 users. On running delta link, I see the response showing 5 users. I deleted these 5 users from AAD (**Note that I deleted users from *Azure Active Directory***). And these users were automatically removed from the AAD group that they belonged to. On running the delta link, I see no response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
"@odata.deltaLink": "",
"value": []
}
```

Is this a bug? Why is the response not showing the users removed from the group because they were deleted from AAD?

Answer (score 0):

From the response the `odata.context` is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups`. You are calling delta query on `groups` not on `users`.

Call delta query on `users`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
```

Based on this [comment](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14708#issuecomment-959795309), delta query on groups doesn't show any group membership changes due to the deletion of a member.

Comment: I need to find out difference of users in a group.

Comment: Meaning I need to find membership changes in a group

Comment: @user989988 please check updated answer with a link to a discussion where is mentioned that delta query on group doesn't show changes due to the deletion of a member. It's by design.

Comment: Ok thank you! Is there an api to get users removed from an AAD group because they longer present in AAD? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842380/graph-api-to-find-out-users-removed-from-aad