# Graph API to find out users deleted om AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an AAD group in which I added 5 users. On running delta link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#deltalink-response), I see the response showing 5 users. I deleted these 5 users from AAD (**Note that I deleted users from *Azure Active Directory***). And these users were automatically removed from the AAD group that they belonged to. On running the delta link, I see no response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
"@odata.deltaLink": "",
"value": []
}
```

My assumption was delta link would show these removed users. If that's not the case, is there a Graph API that returns users removed from an AAD group because they longer present in AAD?

I saw this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

On running this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true

I see all the users that were deleted from AAD.

Is there a way to get users removed from an AAD group because they longer present in AAD?

Comment: How exactly do you remove the user? Do you only delete the user from AAD or delete the user from a group and then remove the user from AAD?

Comment: Deleted the user from AAD

Comment: Try to remove users from group before deleting them from group and check if delta query groups returns info about removed users.

Comment: When I run delta query on a group https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id  eq 'id', I see the all the users in the group (added & deleted). The response will also include a delta link in the response so that the next time, I can use the delta link to find out if are there any NEW users added & removed from the group instead of reading the ENTIRE group. When I remove the users from the group, delta link shows the removed users. When I delete the users from the AAD, the users get removed from the groups they belonged to. And delta link doesn't show the deleted users.

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one **Azure AD group** and added **`5 users`** to it like below:

[image]

Now, when I ran the **delta query** on groups, I got the results successfully as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,description,members
```

**Response:**

[image]

I deleted those 5 users, and they are automatically removed from the group like below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now, when I ran the below query including **filter**, I got those 5 removed users in that **group** with reason as **`deleted`** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta/?$filter=id eq 'group_id' &$select=id,displayName,members
```

**Response:**
[image]

I too got the **delta link** in the response like below:

[image]

But when I ran that **delta link**, I'm getting **`empty`** results same as you like below:

[image]

So, instead of running **delta link**, just execute the **`normal query`** like below to get the results:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta/?$filter=id eq 'group_id' &$select=id,displayName,members
```

Otherwise, instead of deleting the users directly from Azure AD, remove the users from the group first and run the query.

Comment: But the normal query would return all the users in the group is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it will return both existing and deleted users in the group. But you can identify **deleted** users specifically that comes with `@removed` parameter.

Comment: 2 questions: in your query, I don't see the url including a group id: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,description,members. Does that mean it will show results from all AAD groups? 2) When we run a delta query on a group, we get a delta link in the response and we use this delta link in the next call so that we only get difference in the group instead of all the users. I don't see a delta link in your response. Why is that?

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you! My idea behind using delta link was to reduce the cost associated with reading entire membership of the group. Sounds like delta link is not useful anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248352/discussion-between-sridevi-and-user989988).

Comment: If I run https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta/?$filter=id eq 'group_id' &$select=id,displayName,members does it show users deleted from AAD that belonged to group

Comment: Yes, it will show...I did the same and got the results

Comment: hmm interesting. Thanks! Could you please answer this question if you have an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860367/difference-between-groups-delta-and-groups

Comment: Could you please reply to this comment - My idea behind using delta link was to reduce the cost associated with reading entire membership of the group. Sounds like delta link is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is removed from AAD the user is also removed from all groups and it's not possible to find out in which group/groups the user was in.

Try to remove users from group before deleting them from AAD.