# Difference between groups/delta and /groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id  eq 'id' [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups]

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/id/members [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http]

What is the difference between the above two queries? 1st one returns membership of a group with details like '@removed' users + delta link and 2nd one returns membership of a group without details like '@removed' users. Is that the only difference? What is the cost associated with running these 2 queries in terms of performance, compute time?

Answer (score 1):

Delta query enables applications to discover newly created, updated, or deleted entities without performing a full read of the target resource with every request. it helps to track the changes .

where as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/id/members return all the members data.

please read the doc for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Hope that's helps

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Question - from doc it says delta query shows incremental changes

Comment: Does it show all users in a group during the initial call?

Comment: My question is about delta query

Comment: When I run https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter=id eq 'group_id' does it show all users in the group?

Comment: Nope ,the delta query only enables you to discover changes without fetching the entire set of groups to compare changes. If you want to get the list of members in that group, you need to use the normal query in that case https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/id/members , please check the docs to see the list of supported resources - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment", thanks